# How to fix "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread" on a Linux development laptop

Tags: performance, testing, jvm

I am developing and running automated JVM Java performance tests on my laptop. Most of them use many thread pools extensively. I run into the following issue:

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread`

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode).

How can I develop and run my performance tests locally on my laptop before I submit them to being run in the performance test environment?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that should satisfy some use cases is to increase the cap on number of processes a user can run.

Ubuntu desktop OS by default has a comparatively low cap on number of user processes, compared to production-grade Unix server configurations.

To increase the number of max user processes for all users open `/etc/security/limits.conf` and change the default number (likely to be 4096) to a higher one (for example 16384), for example:

```
* soft     nproc          16384
* hard     nproc          16384
```

Other solutions to contemplate:

- Run less JVM threads in your local environment to develop and test your suite of tests and full number of threads in the real performance test environment
- Develop your tests locally but always run them in the performance test environment